# The system cannot find the file specified. error for .p12 certificate file

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have used a .p12 certificate file given by google to fetch the data from google analytics API. All things work fine in my pc with visual studio dev server. but when I publish it to the production IIS server, I get "The system cannot find the file specified." error.

the code to to get the file path,

var keyFilePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/xxxxxx.p12");

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found the solution. when it is running in IIS, I need to set "Load User Profile" to True in the application pool's advanced settings to be able to load a cert by filename & password

Answer (score 1):

According to your descritpion, I suggest you could firstly check your IIS application folder to make sure you have copy the .p12 certificate file to the IIS folder.

I guess you miss copy the file when publish the application to IIS.

I suggest you could right click the .p12 certificate file in VS and click copy always as below:

[image]

Comment: I have checked the file in the folder and it is there. And I have enabled the copy always option as well. but still no luck

Comment: I suggest you could output the keyFilePath in your application's page to make sure this path is redirect to the right path in your IIS application.

Comment: I did that. It gives the exact file path. but still  I get "The system cannot find the file specified." error

Comment: Could you please share the path details?