# Opening a certificate file in the root IIS folder returns "System cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm opening a Google API connection in a C#/MVC application.  It works great on my VS session but when I deploy it the certificate file for Google cannot be loaded.

I get an error

> "The system cannot find the file specified."

The file I am attempting to open is C`:\inetpub\[website]\mygoogleapp.p12`

I have verified this file exists on the server.

The code I use to open the certificate is here:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory  + serviceAccountCertPath,
                                                   serviceAccountCertPassword,
                                                   X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

I also verified that the path is correct for the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + serviceAccountCertPath`

I'm assuming there's an issue with reading the file that's sitting there.  I found this which is the same issue but I cannot "Load User Profile" to true.  [The system cannot find the file specified. error for .p12 certificate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329636/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-error-for-p12-certificate-file)

Is there another way around this?

Comment: Silly but maybe.... did you check the IIS USERS permissions over the folder?

Comment: It was not a permissions issue.  I didn't find a way around this so I moved the certificate to the DB instead.

Comment: Well, it sounds like permissions issues with extra steps

Comment: I can open other cert files (but using a different access method) there so I ruled that out. Regardless, I opted to go another direction.  I can't modify the IIS installation; it would have to be done through code.